# Determining the bounds of a given region

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

Given $A = \{(s,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2; s \geq 0, t \geq 0, s^2 + t^2 \leq 1\}$.

This region is the first quadrant of a circle centered at $0$ with radius $r=1$.

I want to determine the bounds of $s$ and $t$. My approach:

$s^2 + t^2 \leq 1 \implies s^2 \leq 1 - t^2 \implies s \leq \sqrt{1 - t^2}$

$\implies 0 \leq s \leq \sqrt{1 - t^2}$.

However, I don't know how to find the upper bound of $t$. Is it also given by $t \leq \sqrt{1 - s^2}$? I am not sure but it confuses me that both bounds depend on the other variable.

Comment: The way you should interpret this is for a given $t \in [0,1]$ we have $0 \leq s \leq \sqrt{1-t^2}$. So $t$ varies in the interval $[0,1]$ and based on that your $s$ will be bounded. For example, if $t=\frac{1}{2}$, then $0 \leq s \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: @AnuragA Could I switch this also and interpret this for a given $s \in [0,1]$?

Comment: yes of course you can.